# converting a string to a void pointer

Tags: c, casting, swap, void-pointers

I'm trying to figure out how to "transform" strings (char*) to void* and viceversa.
When I execute this my output is just the first printf and ignores the second one, it doesn't even write "after = "

PS This little program is just to understand, I know i could actually use swap(&s[0],&s[1]). I need to know how to properly cast a void pointer into an array of strings.
I'm working on a uni project where I need to create my own quick_sort algorythm and I need the swap function inside of it to work with void pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void swap(char** x,char** y);

static void swap(char** x,char** y){
    char* temp=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=temp;
}

int main()
{
    char* s[2];
    s[0]="weee";
    s[1]="yooo";
    void* array=s;
    printf("before %s %s\n",s[0],s[1]);
    swap((&array)[0],(&array)[1]);
    printf("after = %s %s",(char*)array,(char*)array);
    return 0;
}
```

I think I'm missing something big
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is it you want to achieve? You are currently assigning the address of a `char*`pointer to a `void*` pointer. That is a different level of indirection.

Comment: `char* s[2]` declares an array of 2 elements of type `char*`, i.e. an array of two strings.

Comment: `(&array)[1]` Here `&array` again is the address (not the value) of a pointer (a variable on the stack) and then you do address arithmetic grabbing whatever comes next on the stack. That's fishy....

Comment: You need `void **array = s;` ... just changed the 2 commented lines: https://ideone.com/cmCErv

Comment: You  might try `swap(&s[0], &s[1]);`

Comment: @pmg: `void **array = s` is not proper either. While the C standard requires `char *` and `void *` to have the same representation, using `array[i]` to access `s[i]` would violate aliasing rules.

Comment: @Gerhardh 
I added a PS in the post to clarify.
Thanks for the kind answers

Comment: @SupportUkraine  I added a PS in the post to clarify. Thanks for the kind answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this declaration the array `s` used as an initializer is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `char **`.

```
void* array = s;
```

In the call of the function `swap`

```
swap((&array)[0],(&array)[1]);
```

the first argument can be the pointer `array` itself that will be implicitly casted to the pointer type of the corresponding parameter

```
swap( array, (&array)[1]);
```

But you need to correctly pass the second argument. To do this you need to cast the pointer `array` explicitly like

```
swap( array, ( char ** )array + 1 );
```

In the call of `printf` you need also correctly to supply argument expressions.

Here is your updated program

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void swap(char** x,char** y);

static void swap(char** x,char** y){
    char* temp=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=temp;
}

int main()
{
    char* s[2];
    s[0]="weee";
    s[1]="yooo";
    void* array=s;
    printf("before %s %s\n",s[0],s[1]);
    swap( array, ( char ** )array + 1 );
    printf("after = %s %s", *(char**)array, ( (char**)array )[1]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
before weee yooo
after = yooo weee
```

Comment: YESS that's what I needed to understand! THANKS

Answer (score 1):

`void *array = s;` declares `array` to be a `void *`. Then `&array` is the address of that `void *`, so `&array[1]` would access a `void *` after it. But there is no `void *` after it, since `void *array` defines a single `void *`.

`array` could be properly defined to alias `s` with `char **array = s;`, after which `swap(&array[0], &array[1]);` would work as desired.

If you define array as `void **array = (void **) s;`, then `swap(&array[0], &array[1]);` will produce diagnostic messages because the types are wrong. You could use `swap((char **) &array[0], (char **) &array[1]);`.

Then, if you print the strings with `printf("after = %s %s", array[0], array[1]);`, this will work, although it is not entirely proper code. Using `array[0]` as an argument passes a `void *` where `printf` is expecting a `char *` for the `%s`. However, the C standard guarantees that `void *` and `char *` have the same representation (encode their values using bytes in memory in the same way), and it further says (in a non-normative note) that this is intended to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions.

Answer (score 1):

The `void*` doesn't seem to fulfil any particular purpose here, just swap the pointers: `swap(&s[0],&s[1]);`.

You could also do this:

```
char** ptr = &s[0];
printf("before %s %s\n",ptr[0],ptr[1]);
swap(&ptr[0],&ptr[1]);
printf("after = %s %s",ptr[0],ptr[1]);
```

If you for reasons unknown insist on using `void*` then note that as your code stands, it points at the first `char*` in your array of `char*`. However, it isn't possible to perform pointer arithmetic on `void*` since that would entail knowing how large a "`void`" is. The `void*` doesn't know that it points at an array of pointers. Therefore `array[i]` is nonsense.

Also, the `void*` are set to point at `char*` so you simply cannot pass it to a function expecting a `char**`. You'd have to rewrite the whole program in a needlessly obfuscated way, so just abandon that idea.

Comment: General rule of thumb: `void*` should pretty much never be present in a beginner-level program (perhaps with the exception of using bsearch/qsort).

Comment: yeah, I need to understand to create my own qsort()
Thank you for your answer!